# Can we change "You have 1 new answer; 1 new comment" to something grammatically correct?

Tags: feature-request, localization, grammar

When you get new answers and comments, Stack Overflow tells you "You have 1 new answer; 1 new comment." As far as I understand, that's not how semicolons work. Here are a couple suggestions for what could be used instead:

- You have 1 new answer, 1 new
  comment
- You have 1 new answer and 1 new
  comment

Comment: +1, but `[status-deferred]` until the team tackles site localization.

Comment: Well, just change it for english.stackexchange.com

Comment: At least the pluralization is correct!